# How to get last Thursday date or Wednesday date of current month in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe in which I have dates. I want to take each date from `nf_date` column and get last Thursday of that month if last Thursday date is not present in `nf_date` column then take last Wednesday date `(which is previous of last Thursday) of that month.` After getting the last Thursday or Wednesday date i want to append that date in current dataframe in new column name `expiry`  [my code is pasted in this link](https://code.labstack.com/dRI0CBQ1)

Answer (score 0):

you can obtain the specific weekday by going back from the month's end date:

```
import pandas as pd

# a dummy example
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-10-29', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-16']})
#       month last Thursday: 2021-10-28,   2021-11-25,   2021-12-30

# we have a datetime series in our dataframe...
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# we can easily get the month's end date:
df['mEnd'] = df['date'] + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1)

# Thursday is weekday 3, so the offset for given weekday is
offset = (df['mEnd'].dt.weekday - 3) % 7

# now to get the date of the last Thursday of the month, subtract it from 
# month end date:
df['last_Thrs'] = df['mEnd'] - pd.to_timedelta(offset, unit='D')

print(df)
#         date       mEnd  last_Thrs
# 0 2021-10-29 2021-10-31 2021-10-28
# 1 2021-11-01 2021-11-30 2021-11-25
# 2 2021-12-16 2021-12-31 2021-12-30
```